# dplyr - group last n row values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe as below

```
+--------+-----------+-----+
|  make  |   model   | cnt |
+--------+-----------+-----+
| toyota |  camry    |  10 |
| toyota |  corolla  |   4 |
| honda  |  city     |   8 |
| honda  |  accord   |  13 |
| jeep   |  compass  |   3 |
| jeep   |  wrangler |   5 |
| jeep   |  renegade |   1 |
| accura |  x1       |   2 |
| accura |  x3       |   1 |
+--------+-----------+-----+
```

I need to aggregate this dataframe by `Make` so as to get the total volume and share - I do this as follows.

```
df <- data.frame(Make=c('toyota','toyota','honda','honda','jeep','jeep','jeep','accura','accura'),
                 Model=c('camry','corolla','city','accord','compass', 'wrangler','renegade','x1', 'x3'),
                 Cnt=c(10, 4, 8, 13, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1))
dfc <- df %>%
  group_by(Make) %>%
  summarise(volume = sum(Cnt)) %>%
  mutate(share=volume/sum(volume)*100.0) %>%
  arrange(desc(volume))
```

The above operation gives me the `share` and `volume` aggregated by `Make` as below.

```
+--------+--------+-----------+
| make   | volume | share     |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| honda  | 21     | 44.680851 |
| toyota | 14     | 29.787234 |
| jeep   | 9      | 19.148936 |
| accura | 3      | 6.382979  |
+--------+--------+-----------+
```

I need to group everything `except the first two rows` to a group `others` and also aggregate the `volume` and `share` such that the dataframe would look like below.

```
+--------+--------+-----------+
| make   | volume | share     |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| honda  | 21     | 44.680851 |
| toyota | 14     | 29.787234 |
| others | 12     | 25.53191  |
+--------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: There are many ways to do that and really depends on the logic of your second grouping. Will you ALWAYS want to group everything apart from first two rows? Is there a name matching? A `Volume` threshold maybe?

Comment: not always,in the sense that `two` is an example - but lets say group everything except the first `n` rows - the rows are sorted by 'desc` `volume`.

Comment: Got it. I was thinking whether a `volume` or a `share` threshold is a better method to group your data. In a way that you don't have to manually specify it. Eg. Group together everything with a `share` less than 25%. In this way it will ALWAYS be a 25% threshold, but that might refer to 2,3,4,... rows.

Comment: If they'll be in sort order when you do it, could you create a temp var to aggregate on? `df$temp <- c(1, 2, ..., n, rep(n+1, nrow(df)-n)` where you have `n` groups. Then just aggregate on that variable. It could also be recoded appropriately, I just did numbers for simplicity here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

# example data
df <- data.frame(Make=c('toyota','toyota','honda','honda','jeep','jeep','jeep','accura','accura'),
                 Model=c('camry','corolla','city','accord','compass', 'wrangler','renegade','x1', 'x3'),
                 Cnt=c(10, 4, 8, 13, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1), stringsAsFactors = F)

# specify number of rows
row_threshold = 2

df %>%
  group_by(Make) %>%
  summarise(volume = sum(Cnt)) %>%
  mutate(share=volume/sum(volume)*100.0) %>%
  arrange(desc(volume)) %>%
  group_by(Make_upd = ifelse(row_number() > row_threshold, "others", Make)) %>%
  summarise(volume = sum(volume),
            share = sum(share))

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Make_upd volume    share
#      <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1    honda     21 44.68085
# 2   others     12 25.53191
# 3   toyota     14 29.78723
```

Comment: I see they order by `volume` descending, so it's very likely they pick the number of rows to group based on a `volume` value. Still think it would be better to use a `volume` value threshold....

Comment: For some reason - I'm not getting the `Make_upd` in the tibble as you have, it holds the row numbers instead - except for `others`. `# A tibble: 3 x 3 Make_upd volume share <chr> <dbl> <dbl> 1 2 21 44.68085 2 4 14 29.78723 3 others 12 25.53191`

Comment: i got it - since I did not use  `stringsAsFactors = F` while creating the dataframe -  , fixed it via  `group_by(Make_upd = ifelse(row_number() > row_threshold, "others", as.character(Make))) %>%`